# Reading variable data from a string

Tags: c++

I am reading through a large log file of bans, and from those bans I want to specify a name within that line (see John below). I then want to print out only the IP of that line. Here are a few lines from an example log file:

> [13:42:51] james preston (IP: 11.111.11.11) was banned by john
>
> [13:42:51] gerald farmer (IP: 222.22.222.22) was offline banned by James
>
> [13:42:51] luke parker (IP: 33.33.333.333) was banned by john

So far I can get the lines of the bans containing "john" however I would like to then extract the IP address from those lines.

```
int main() {
ifstream BanLogs;
BanLogs.open("ban-2019.log");

// Checking to see if the file is open
if (BanLogs.fail()) {
    cerr << "ERROR OPENING FILE" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

string item;
string name = "john";
int count = 0;


//read a file till the end
while (getline(BanLogs, item)) {
    // If the line (item) contains a certain string (name) proceed.
    if (item.find(name) != string::npos) {
        cout << item << endl;
        count++;
    }
}

cout << "Number of lines " << count << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use regular expressions?

Comment: Sorry @G-man, I am new to programming and am unaware of what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are new to programming, here is the most vanilla way:

```
    size_t startIdx = item.find("(IP: ");
    if (startIdx == std::string::npos) continue;
    startIdx += 5; // skip the "(IP: " part
    size_t endIdx = item.find(')', startIdx + 1);
    if (endIdx == std::string::npos) continue;
    cout << item.substr(startIdx, endIdx - startIdx) << endl;
```

This kind of jobs are much easier to do with scripting languages, i.e. Python.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are one option.

Another would be to use `std::string::find` which you are already using to select the relevant lines. You cloud search for `"(IP:"` to get the starting position of the address (The actual starting position is the result of `std::string::find` plus 4 for the length of the search string). Then you can search for `")"` to get the end position of the IP address in the string. Using these two positions you can extract a substring containing the IP address by using [`std::string::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

Comment: Another way is to use [`std::sscanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf)